# Adding threads increases time needed to perform the same task

Tags: c++, windows, parallel-processing

I have been struggling with this for past 3 days. I do some stuff in image processing. I came to a point where I could distribute the workflow to more threads since I had "patches" of image, that I could pass to different threads. Unfortunately, the whole time it took to process the image was the same no matter if using 1 or more threads.

So I started digging, making copies of patches so every thread has its own local data, stopped writing result to array, but it was still the same. So I made the most minimalistic program I could have. After thread was created, it would make 10x10 matrix and write its determinant to console. So nothing shared between, only thing passed was index of a thread.

But it was still the same. I made tests both on Linux and Windows. These show time required to compute one determinant, so when using two threads each one took the same amount of time if not stated otherwise:

Windows:

1 Thread = 4479ms

2 Threads = 7500ms

3 Threads = 11300ms

4 Threads = 15800 ms

Linux:

1 Thread = 490ms

2 Threads = 478ms

3 Threads = First: 503ms; Other two: 1230ms

4 Threads = 1340ms

first thing is obvious, Linux is computing the same thing 10x faster. Nevermind. However windows not that single thread performance is worse, it gets worse no matter how many I add. Linux seems to be slowed down only when workload is being done on logical core. Thats why 1 and 2 are ok, since I have 2Core with HT, and when using 3 threads it slows down on the core that uses HT as well but the other is ok. However windows sucks no matter what.

Funny thing is that on windows it takes +- the same amount of time if I compute 4 determinants on one core or 1 determinant on each core.

The code I was using to get these results. I was able to compile with g++ and msvc no problem. Important are only last few methods, there are some constructors I wasn't sure are not being used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <float.h>

class FVector
{
public:
    FVector();
    FVector(int length);
    FVector(const FVector &vec);
    FVector(FVector &&vec);
    FVector &operator=(const FVector &vec);
    FVector &operator=(FVector &&vec);
    ~FVector();

    void setLength(int length);
    int getLength() const;
    double *getData();
    const double* getConstData() const;

private:
    double *data;
    int length;

    void allocateDataArray(int length);
    void deallocateDataArray();
};

FVector::FVector() {
    data = nullptr;
    length = 0;
}

FVector::FVector(int length) {
    data = nullptr;
    this->length = length;

    allocateDataArray(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = 0.;
    }
}

FVector::FVector(const FVector &vec) {
    allocateDataArray(vec.length);
    length = vec.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = vec.data[i];
    }
}

FVector::FVector(FVector &&vec) {
    data = vec.data;
    vec.data = nullptr;
    length = vec.length;
}

FVector &FVector::operator=(const FVector &vec) {
    deallocateDataArray();

    if (data == nullptr) {
        allocateDataArray(vec.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
            data[i] = vec.data[i];
        }
        length = vec.length;
    }

    return *this;
}

FVector &FVector::operator=(FVector &&vec) {
    deallocateDataArray();

    if (data == nullptr) {
        data = vec.data;
        vec.data = nullptr;
        length = vec.length;
    }

    return *this;
}

FVector::~FVector() {
    deallocateDataArray();
}

void FVector::allocateDataArray(int length) {
    data = new double[length];
}

void FVector::deallocateDataArray() {
    if (data != nullptr) {
        delete[] data;
    }

    data = nullptr;
}

int FVector::getLength() const {
    return length;
}

double *FVector::getData() {
    return data;
}

void FVector::setLength(int length) {
    deallocateDataArray();
    allocateDataArray(length);
    this->length = length;
}

const double* FVector::getConstData() const {
    return data;
}

class FMatrix
{
public:
    FMatrix();
    FMatrix(int columns, int rows);
    FMatrix(const FMatrix &mat);
    FMatrix(FMatrix &&mat);
    FMatrix& operator=(const FMatrix &mat);
    FMatrix& operator=(FMatrix &&mat);
    ~FMatrix();

    FVector *getData();
    const FVector* getConstData() const;
    void makeIdentity();
    int determinant() const;

private:
    FVector *data;
    int columns;
    int rows;

    void deallocateDataArray();
    void allocateDataArray(int count);
};


FMatrix::FMatrix() {
    data = nullptr;
    columns = 0;
    rows = 0;
}

FMatrix::FMatrix(int columns, int rows) {
    data = nullptr;
    allocateDataArray(columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        data[i].setLength(rows);
    }

    this->columns = columns;
    this->rows = rows;
}

FMatrix::FMatrix(const FMatrix &mat) {
    data = nullptr;
    allocateDataArray(mat.columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.columns; i++) {
        data[i].setLength(mat.data[i].getLength());
        data[i] = mat.data[i];
    }

    columns = mat.columns;
    rows = mat.rows;
}

FMatrix::FMatrix(FMatrix &&mat) {
    data = mat.data;
    mat.data = nullptr;

    columns = mat.columns;
    rows = mat.rows;
}

FMatrix &FMatrix::operator=(const FMatrix &mat) {
    deallocateDataArray();

    if (data == nullptr) {
        allocateDataArray(mat.columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < mat.columns; i++) {
            data[i].setLength(mat.rows);
            data[i] = mat.data[i];
        }
    }

    columns = mat.columns;
    rows = mat.rows;

    return *this;
}

FMatrix &FMatrix::operator=(FMatrix &&mat) {
    deallocateDataArray();

    data = mat.data;
    mat.data = nullptr;

    columns = mat.columns;
    rows = mat.rows;

    return *this;
}

FMatrix::~FMatrix() {
    deallocateDataArray();
}

void FMatrix::deallocateDataArray() {
    if (data != nullptr) {
        delete[] data;
    }

    data = nullptr;
}

void FMatrix::allocateDataArray(int count) {
    data = new FVector[count];
}

FVector *FMatrix::getData() {
    return data;
}

void FMatrix::makeIdentity() {
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                data[i].getData()[j] = 1.;
            }
            else {
                data[i].getData()[j] = 0.;
            }
        }
    }
}

int FMatrix::determinant() const {
    int det = 0;
    FMatrix subMatrix(columns - 1, rows - 1);
    int subi;

    if (columns == rows && rows == 1) {
        return data[0].getData()[0];
    }

    if (columns != rows) {
        //throw EXCEPTIONS::SINGULAR_MATRIX;
    }

    if (columns == 2)
        return ((data[0].getConstData()[0] * data[1].getConstData()[1]) - (data[1].getConstData()[0] * data[0].getConstData()[1]));
    else {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            subi = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

                for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {

                    if (x == i) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    subMatrix.data[subi].getData()[j - 1] = data[i].getConstData()[j];
                }

                if (x != i) {
                    subi++;
                }
            }

            det += (pow(-1, x) * data[x].getConstData()[0] * subMatrix.determinant());
        }
    }

    return det;
}

const FVector* FMatrix::getConstData() const {
    return data;
}

class FCore
{
public:
    FCore();
    ~FCore();

    void process();

private:
    int getMaxThreads() const;
    void joinThreads(std::thread *threads, int max);
};


void parallelTest(int i) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    FMatrix m(10, 10);
    m.makeIdentity();
    std::cout << "Det: " << i << "= " << m.determinant() << std::endl;
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish - start);
    std::cout << "Time: " << microseconds.count() / 1000. << std::endl;
}

FCore::FCore()
{
}


FCore::~FCore()
{
}

void FCore::process() {
    /*********************************************/
    /*Set this to limit number of created threads*/
    int threadCount =  getMaxThreads();
    /*********************************************/
    /*********************************************/
    std::cout << "Thread count: " << threadCount;
    std::thread *threads = new std::thread[threadCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(parallelTest, i);
    }

    joinThreads(threads, threadCount);
    delete[] threads;
    getchar();
}

int FCore::getMaxThreads() const {
    int count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    if (count == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return count;
    }
}

void FCore::joinThreads(std::thread *threads, int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

int main() {
    FCore core;

    core.process();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously I've done some testing with more primitive ones, as simple as adding numbers and it was the same. So I just wanted to ask if any of you have ever stumbled on something remotely similar to this. I know that I won't be able to get the awesome time on windows as it is on Linux, but at least the scaling could be better.

Tested on Win7/Linux intel 2C+2T and Win10 ryzen 8C+8T. Times posted are from 2C+2T

Comment: Did you compile your code with optimizations both for Linux and Windows? I would not trust any performance measurement with an unoptimized program.

Comment: You're measuring wall clock time. You could be getting preempted by background processes.

Comment: O3 for linux, O2 for windows. I am not sure how else should I measure

Comment: However it doesn't even matter that much what I write to console, I measured the time it took to do the whole image on the phone and it was very similar.